# codeigniter 2.x.x and paypal express checkout

Tags: php, codeigniter

my CI 2.x.x based app should have an express checkout button, what's the best way to approach this? is there a ready made thing to implement it without having to write a long file of php code? , the whole paypal api seem very huge for me to read to just implement a simple checkout process in a small project

Answer (score 0):

you can use the existing Codeigniter [PayPal Library](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PayPal_Lib/).

More info: [PayPal IPN with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978261/paypal-ipn-with-codeigniter)